# Can't curl a website on production web, only work in localhost - php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a problem when curl the website:
http://hdonline.vn/phim-into-the-badlands-3-15477.html

Here is real code (it's working in localhost):

```
<?php
    /**
     * Get a web file (HTML, XHTML, XML, image, etc.) from a URL.  Return an
     * array containing the HTTP server response header fields and content.
     */
    function get_web_page( $url )
    {
        $user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0';

        $options = array(

            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  =>"GET",        //set request type post or get
            CURLOPT_POST           =>false,        //set to GET
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $user_agent, //set user agent
            CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     =>"cookie.txt", //set cookie file
            CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      =>"cookie.txt", //set cookie jar
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
            CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
            CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
        );

        $ch      = curl_init( $url );
        curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
        $content = curl_exec( $ch );
        $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
        $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
        $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
        curl_close( $ch );

        $header['errno']   = $err;
        $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
        $header['content'] = $content;
        return $header;
    }
    $result = get_web_page('http://hdonline.vn/phim-into-the-badlands-3-15477.html');

    if ( $result['errno'] != 0 )
        echo 'lỗi';

    if ( $result['http_code'] != 200 )
        echo 'không có trang, ko có quyền';

    $page = $result['content'];
    print_r($page);
?>
```

You can copy all code and create the new page to test.

The problem is: I upload source into my VPS, here is production site: 
https://sharengay.com/hdonline/curlhdonline.php

It's don't show anything.

In localhost:
[image]

In https://sharengay.com/hdonline:
[image]

I was added this code in the first php file to pass:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```

Comment: cross origin issue?

Comment: If it's working on local and not on production. Then you should verify that server configuration on production is same as in local. Maybe production server doesn't have curl module installed. Also debug and let us know what issue is on production server.

Comment: if the curl module is not installed, there should be exception message, right?

Comment: @LovepreetSingh I check in my VPS. The curl module was installed. Have any method to debug?

Comment: @TerryWei I was change to curl 'google.com' and it working.. Seem this website block all request. can you check on localhost

Comment: what if you use browser request? what will you get?

Comment: I using Chrome and Firefox. Url to cUrl is: http://hdonline.vn/phim-into-the-badlands-3-15477.html
I get a website, in localhost the cUrl working. In production website, it not working. I added the image to show more information the error I receive.